# Setting Application Icon from My.Resources?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, icons

I can set the application icon by code from a icon resource of my.resources?

PS: The application icon, not the form icon (Me.icon =...)

Comment: What do you mean? The icon in the EXE file?

Comment: possible duplicate, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/334231/how-to-set-ico-i-want-to-use-as-application-icon-in-c

Comment: @Slaks yes, i know that can be done in the application tab of the project settings, i'm asking if I can do it with code

Comment: @Tianyun Ling, is not a duplicate, in that post the user is asking how to do it, i'm asking if I can do it using code, not using the project settings tab

Comment: @ElektroHacker: Of course not.  Windows Explorer is not going to run your code every time it displays the icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking how to set the Application Icon at design time?

Project properties  Application tab

Comment: I'm asking if that is possible without touching the project properties